# Insert in between the letters of String

Tags: java, scala

I have to split it and put `%20` in between of the digits

```
var code="247834"
```

to

```
2%204%207%208%203%204
```

looks simple but i am not able to convert it.
any answer in scala or java is appreciated.

Comment: *First*, pick a language and try an attempt. *Second*, ask here.

Comment: @hexafraction sorry for not showing my attempt. and for language i have to do this in scala but i thinked that i will convert it in scala

Comment: Looks like this question becomes [*code golf*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) type of question

Comment: The answers here are very opinion based. Please clarify which language you prefer... You mention that Java is the prefereed way. Please take a look at my solution and try it out.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl java and scala are similar so i prefer both of them.

Comment: Not really code golf as solutions are in different languages. Some of the solutions which do things character by character would be more relevant if memory was a big issue, which it rarely is nowadays

Comment: @om-nom-nom - This is not code golf.  There is one canonical way to do it in Scala.  (Which user3189923 already posted.)

Comment: @RexKerr [previously there were scala and javascript in tags](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23606493/revisions), java in question body, plus answer in PHP. Not a code golf you saying?

Comment: @om-nom-nom - No, that just makes it a poorly-asked question.  There is no optimization being asked for, just "what's the right way to do this?"  (Both pre-and-post edits.)

Comment: @RexKerr Don't take it way too serious, I was half-joking stating that this is code golf (otherwise, I would point to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Scala,

```
code.mkString("%20")
```

Comment: Not a Scala expert, but don't you need a toList or toCharArray in there...?

Comment: @vogomatix Good question, Scala implicit conversions, see http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/strings.html

Answer (score 4):

In whatever language, your general technique should be to split the string into an array and then join it with the string '%20'. In PHP this would be

```
$array = str_split( $code);
$result = join( '%20', $array);
```

In Javascript:

```
var code="247834";
var myArray = code.split();
var result = myArray.join( '%20');
```

In one statement:

```
var result = code.split().join('%20'); 
// or "247834".split().join('%20');
```

Java??:

```
char[] myArray = "247844".toCharArray();
char[] result = StringUtils.join( myArray, '%20');
```

(the latter may need minor changes e.g. a join method is in TextUtils for Android and swaps the parameter order)

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript

```
var code = "247834";
var output = '';

for (var i = 0; i < code.length; ++i)
{
    output = output + code.charAt(i) + ((i < code.length - 1) ? '%20' : '');

}

alert(output);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sNrU7/1/

Answer (score 0):

## Java solution

Starting from the end, you can insert a delimiter using string buffer. This is the easiest solution and may not be the fastest.

### Output

```
2%204%207%208%203%204  
2-4-7-8-3-4
```

### Code

```java
import java.lang.StringBuffer;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "247834";
        System.out.println(separate(str, "%20"));
        System.out.println(separate(str, "-"));
    }

    public static String separate(String str, String delim) {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(str);

        for (int i = str.length(); i > 0 ; i--) {
            if (i < str.length()) {
                buff.insert(i, delim);
            }
        }

        return buff.toString();
    }
}
```